# Send Email with C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, email

I am using this code to send an email with an attachment when a button is clicked  in my windows 8 application

For this I am using the [EASendMail](http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/c_xaml.aspx?cat=0) SMTP component which I had to install and reference in my app.

```
 private async void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnSend.IsEnabled = false;
            await Send_Email();
            btnSend.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        private async Task Send_Email()
        {
            String Result = "";
            try
            {
                SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
                SmtpClient oSmtp = new SmtpClient();

                // Set sender email address, please change it to yours
                oMail.From = new MailAddress("test@emailarchitect.net");

                // Add recipient email address, please change it to yours
                oMail.To.Add(new MailAddress("support@emailarchitect.net"));

                // Set email subject
                oMail.Subject = "test email from C# XAML project with file attachment";

                // Set Html body
                oMail.HtmlBody = "<font size=5>This is</font> <font color=red><b>a test</b></font>";

                // get a file path from PicturesLibrary, 
                // to access files in PicturesLibrary, you MUST have "Pictures Library" checked in
                // your project -> Package.appxmanifest -> Capabilities
                Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = 
                    await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync("test.jpg");

                string attfile = file.Path;
                Attachment oAttachment = await oMail.AddAttachmentAsync(attfile);

                // if you want to add attachment from remote URL instead of local file.
                // string attfile = "http://www.emailarchitect.net/test.jpg";
                // Attachment oAttachment = await oMail.AddAttachmentAsync(attfile);

                // you can change the Attachment name by
                // oAttachment.Name = "mytest.jpg";

                // Your SMTP server address
                SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("smtp.emailarchitect.net");

                // User and password for ESMTP authentication            
                oServer.User = "test@emailarchitect.net";
                oServer.Password = "testpassword";

                // If your SMTP server requires TLS connection on 25 port, please add this line
                // oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;

                // If your SMTP server requires SSL connection on 465 port, please add this line
                // oServer.Port = 465;
                // oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;

                await oSmtp.SendMailAsync(oServer, oMail);
                Result = "Email was sent successfully!";
            }
            catch (Exception ep)
            {
                Result = String.Format("Failed to send email with the following error: {0}", ep.Message);
            }

            // Display Result by Diaglog box
            Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog dlg = new
                Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(Result);

            await dlg.ShowAsync();
        }
```

But when I click the button, I get an error message "Failed to send email with the following error: Access is denied"

How do I fix this?

EDIT:

After enabling the pictures library I know get this message:

[image]

EDIT:

I did some further work and noticed that the email send fine without the attachment.

It works without this code:

```
  Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = 
                        await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync("test.jpg");

                    string attfile = file.Path;
                    Attachment oAttachment = await oMail.AddAttachmentAsync(attfile);
```

But I need the attachment to be sent also.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What's the full error message **and** stack trace?

Comment: You are using `PicturesLibrary`, have you set capabilities to access picture library in manifest?

Comment: When I enabled the picture library capability, I now get a different error. "Failed to send email with the following error: The parameter is incorrect"

Comment: @Arran in my above question and comment, that is the full error message shown to me on the screen

Comment: You aren't even capturing the full thing. Change: `Result = String.Format("Failed to send email with the following error: {0}", ep.Message);` to: `Result = String.Format("Failed to send email with the following error: {0}", ep.ToString());` ...show us what is returned after that.